# Снифф трафика с локального вебсервера

Tags: php

Подскажите, есть локальный сервер. С помощью php делаю запросы, как мне отловить эти запросы? Пробовал Чарли и Фиддлер, они видят только то что в браузере.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '');
$ss = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Нужны подробности: как именно вы делаете запросы, где и зачем вы хотите их отлавливать, что именно вы хотите получить, пример вашего кода, и что именно в нем не работает и т.д.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev   Добавил код, я хочу видеть что отослал curl, какие заголовки и пр.

Comment: wireshark попробуйте.

Comment: В каком месте хотите просматривать? В php коде или в стороннем приложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настрой в curl'е использование прокси, который создаёт фиддлер. Скорее всего, `localhost:7777` или `localhost:8888`.